# Fix-position something at the bottom of facebook iframe?

Tags: css, facebook

I need to position somehting at the bottom of an facebook iframe. As it's an iframe i can't just fix-position it. Facebook provides an api that gives me the data I need. This is the best I've come up with:

```
setInterval(function(){
        FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(info){
            var windowheight = info.clientHeight;
            var iframeoffset = info.offsetTop;
            var scrolloffset = info.scrollTop;
            var offset = windowheight-iframeoffset+scrolloffset-30+'px';
            $('#legal').css("top",offset);
    });
},1);
```

It works but the bottom line sort of glitches around when I scroll to fast as the framerate is maximum 1000fps (even in Chrome, I haven't even dared to try it in any other browsers yet). Is there any less complicated and/or less laggy way to do

Answer (score 0):

Can you include css in the application that gives the div absolute positioning?

```
div {
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: nope, because it's inside an iframe, and also I want a fixed position, not an absolute position

Answer (score 0):

There really is no other way to fixed position in a Facebook iframe. I would recommend using

```
$('#legal').animate({position: "absolute", top: offset}, 500);
```

so that at least it transitions smoothly. You could make the transition time relative to the distance it is traveling as well.